# Problem with proof in "Topics in Algebra" by Herstein.

Tags: ring-theory

On pg. 148 of the second edition, the proof for the unique factorization theorem in Euclidean rings is given. 
Let $\pi_{1}.\pi_{2}.\pi_{3}\dots = \pi_{1}'.\pi_{2}'.\pi_{3}'\dots\dots$, where all the elements are distinct prime elements of the ring. Then, the proof says $\pi_{1}$ divides some $\pi_{i}'$.

**(1) I don't understand why $\pi_{1}$ can't divide multiple $\pi_{i}'$s. I don't see why there can't be another $\pi_{j}'=u_{j}.\pi_{1}$, where $u_{j}$ is a unit of the ring.**

Then it says $\pi_{i}'=u_{1}.\pi_{1}$, where $u_{1}$ is a unit of the ring. So write $\pi_{i}'$ as $u_{1}.\pi_{1}$ on the right-hand side, and cancel $\pi_{1}$ on both sides.

**(2) How can we cancel $\pi_{1}$ when it is not a unit of the ring?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If the primes aren't distinct, it might. Look at $2\cdot2\cdot 3 = (-2)\cdot 2\cdot (-3)$. $2$ divides both $2$ and $-2$. However, this is fine, because we're just getting rid of each prime element one by one. In this example, we can pair $2$ with $2$ or with $-2$: it doesn't matter, because the other will be cancelled by the other $2$ on the left.
If we're assuming each $\pi_i$ to be distinct, then say $\pi_1 = u_i\pi_i'$ and $\pi_1 = u_j\pi_j'$. Then we have $u_j\pi_j' = u_i\pi_i'\implies u_i^{-1}u_j\pi_j' = \pi_i'$, so if $\pi_1$ divides more than one prime on the right, the primes it divides must be associates. However, it appears that the proof isn't saying that $\pi_1$ can't divide more than one: it's simply claiming that there is *at least* one $\pi_i'$ such that $\pi_1 = u_i\pi_i'$.

**2)** We can cancel in any integral domain: say $ab=ac$, $a\neq 0$. Then $ab−ac=a(b−c)=0$, which can only happen if $b−c=0$ or $a=0$: but we assumed that $a\neq 0$, so $b=c$.

Comment: (1) I think I got it from your answer. Even if $\pi_{1}$ divides multiple primes on the right, it definitely divides one. Hence, representing that $\pi_{i}$ as a multiple pf $\pi_{1}$ and subsequent cancellation of $\pi_{1}$ calls for the fact that there HAS to be a divisor on the left for EACH prime number on the right. Hence, number of primes on the left=number of primes on the right. 

(2) You're right. I shouldn't have overlooked this.